# Defining and referencing XSD types in namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, codesynthesis

I know `xmlns` defines a namespace, but I am a bit confused about its use in an XSD file (this is codesynthesis provided example).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--

file      : examples/cxx/parser/library/library.xsd
copyright : not copyrighted - public domain

-->

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:lib="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library"
            targetNamespace="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library">

  <xsd:simpleType name="isbn">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>


  <xsd:complexType name="title">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:simpleType name="genre">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="romance"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="fiction"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="horror"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="history"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="philosophy"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>


  <xsd:complexType name="person">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="born" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="died" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="author">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="lib:person">
    <xsd:attribute name="recommends" type="xsd:IDREF"/> <!-- Book -->
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="book">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="isbn" type="lib:isbn"/>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="lib:title"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="lib:genre"/>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="lib:author" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="available" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="catalog">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="book" type="lib:book" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:element name="catalog" type="lib:catalog"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

Why are the new types which are defined like `person`, `author`referenced with `lib` namespace prefix but not with `xsd`prefix, where both are defined in document? What makes them belong to `lib` but not to `xsd`?

Secondly they are referenced standalone when they are defined but they have namespace prefix when they are being used. Shouldn't they be defined with namespace prefix as well?

For example, `author` doesn't have lib prefix when it is defined but it uses `lib:person` with namespace prefix (and likewise when `author` is used later, it belongs to `lib`!). This adds to the confusion!

```
  <xsd:complexType name="author">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="lib:person">
    <xsd:attribute name="recommends" type="xsd:IDREF"/> <!-- Book -->
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are the new types which are defined like `person`, `author`
>   referenced with lib namespace prefix but not with `xsd` prefix, where
>   both are defined in document? What makes them belong to `lib` but not
>   to `xsd`?

The `xsd` namespace prefix is defined by

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

This namespace is reserved for XML Schema constructs.

The `lib` namespace prefix is defined by

```
xmlns:lib="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library"
```

This namespace is user-defined  (controlled by Codesynthesis, in this case, for its components).

> Secondly they are referenced standalone when they are defined but they
>   have namespace prefix when they are being used. Shouldn't they be
>   defined with namespace prefix as well?

No, for a targetNamespace declaration such as:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library"
```

A definition of a type such as `author` (no namespace prefix here),

```
<xsd:complexType name="author">...</xsd:complexType>
```

is automatically in the `http://www.codesynthesis.com/library` namespace, but must be referenced via the corresponding namespace prefix, `type="lib:author"`.

Comment: The `targetNamespace` and `xmlns` does confuse me. Is `xmlns` roughly equates to `using namespace` in C++ and `targetNamspace`is declaring your own namespace?

Comment: I thought `xmlns` does what apparently `targetNamespace` does, i.e to assign tags to a particular namespace.

Comment: `xs:schema/@targetNamespace="` ***namespaceURI*** `"` declares that the components defined in this schema are in in the ***namespaceURI*** namespace.  This is different than `xmlns`, which is used (1) to define a namespace prefix, *or* (2) to define a default namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The targetNamespace attribute in the schema tag defines the namespace where the elements of the current schema are defined. in your example this is "http://www.codesynthesis.com/library". All the types, attributes and elements defined in the documents belongs to the targetNamespace. In order to get a reference to one of these, you need to define the xmlns for the namespace (in your example xmlns:lib="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library"). So you must to use the defined prefix "lib" only when you get a reference to a type defined in the schema. By the way, you can define your target namespace as default namespace (xmlns="http://www.codesynthesis.com/library") and no prefix are needed for your target namespace.